# Windows Phone - check if MapCore.SetView doesn't zoom too much

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, maps, zooming

I am using method SetView to zoom for two points in map but when they are too close I am too zoomed. So I hope I can check something like this:

```
myMap.SetView(bounds);
if (myMap.ZoomLevel > Constants.DefaultZoomLevel)
    myMap.ZoomLevel = Constants.DefaultZoomLevel;
```

But method SetView isn't immediately set ZoomLevel property. What can I do to fix it? How can I set some zoom level border? Thanks

**Edit:**

I found that in 8.0 sdk there is ZoomLevelChanged event? This could be useful for me. So is there possible how to get it worked in 7.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried several solutions and these are my results (I needed working for WP7.1, with just targeting for WP8 there could be easier solution):

- Use of TargetZoomLevel

Like this:

```
myMap.ZoomLevel = Math.Min(myMap.TargetZoomLevel, maxZoomLevel);
```

Doesn't solve my problem because SetView set ZoomLevel after this code execute. Map was just blinking between ZoomLevel from SetView and maxZoomLevel (I have timer for checking positions so that is why it was blinking and isn't good for me).

- Use of MapZoom event

Like this:

```
private void map1_MapZoom(object sender, Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.MapZoomEventArgs e)
{
    if (((Map)sender).ZoomLevel > maxZoomLevel)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Problem: MapZoom event handler is not fired when SetView it's used.

- Check distance and set ZoomLevel if distance is little:

  ```
  public static double GetDistanceBetweenPoints(LatLon firstPoint, LatLon secondPoint)
  {
      var sCoord = new GeoCoordinate(firstPoint.Lat, firstPoint.Lon);
      var eCoord = new GeoCoordinate(secondPoint.Lat, secondPoint.Lon);
      return sCoord.GetDistanceTo(eCoord);
  }
  ```

usage:

```
var distance = LocationHelper.GetDistanceBetweenPoints(carPosition, userPosition);
if (distance < MinMetersDistance)
    myMap.ZoomLevel = maxZoomLevel;
```

Problem: Again blinking. Sometimes I set ZoomLevel by this code. Other time it was set by SetView.

- My real solution:

I just check distance between two points like in previous dot. But this time if the distance was little I just create new points from the old ones and set them in new positions (latitude and longitude) which was in min distance (one on the left side I moved more to left and second on the right side I moved more to right). Then I used SetView on new points.